# How to install ubuntu on uefi mode without using any usb drive while in legacy mode

Tags: uefi

So technically i want to transfer my ubuntu in uefi mode so i can maybe access my windows but the problem is that I dont a have usb or a sdcard to make a bootable device. How do I make a bootable device without a usb in lubuntu

Comment: Would a CD-ROM be acceptable?

Comment: Well I do have a cd and cd slot for my laptop  but some of them contain Movies and some are scratched and old pretty much all of my cd,s are old while some of the are too small maybe i can delete the movie inside the cd

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'transfer'. Do you want to convert an existing installed Ubuntu system from legacy mode to uefi mode? Or do you want to 'copy' and existing installed Ubuntu system? Or do you want make a fresh installation starting from an Ubuntu iso file (via a USB or DVD drive)? Ot something else? Depending on what you want, the method will be very different.

Comment: Please edit your original question to describe with more details what system you have and what [Ubuntu] system you want.

Comment: I want to copy ubuntu to uefi to check if windows is there or use boot repair to find windows in uefi. Boot repair detected a windows efi so im gonna try to copy ubuntu to uefi so I can dual boot -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499036/my-windows-dissapeared-from-the-boot-menu-after-installing-lubuntu?noredirect=1#comment2626170_1499036

Comment: @Kingrain, So you have a Windows system that is booting in uefi mode. Have you got an Ubuntu system booting in legacy mode? In the same computer or in another computer?

Comment: In the same computer technically windows on uefi and ubuntu on legacy now im not sure that windows is in uefi though. Boot repair detected a windows efi so maybe windows is in uefi i Just dont trust boot repair for some reason

Comment: If the 'only' thing you want to improve is that Ubuntu should be able to read files in the Windows `C:` file system, you need not boot Ubuntu in uefi mode, but if Windows has an encrypted file system, you must be able to unlock it, and it might be difficult. If no encryption, and still problems, you should turn off 'Fast Startup' in Windows (which is 'semi-hibernation'). You should see in the uefi-bios menu system, if the computer is set to boot in uefi mode or in legacy mode alias bios mode alias 'csm'. Before trying to change things, you must know what you have.

Comment: What computer is it (brand name and model), and which version of Ubuntu is it and which version of Windows is it? The answer to these quesions help finding the boot mode (uefi or legacy).

Comment: I must soon leave the keyboard, but there are other people that can help you ...

Comment: 1st i already turned off fast startup on legacy but still i cannot boot into windows     2 im using sony viao ,ubuntu LTS 22.04  and windows 10

Comment: Did you change boot mode in an uefi-bios menu when you installed Ubuntu? If not, the boot mode should remain the same (as when there was only Windows), and there is probably another problem that stops Windows from booting. -- If factory installed Windows 10, it boots in uefi mode.

Comment: So you you technically mean that windows is on legacy. But its just blocked by a app or something.

Comment: No, we don't know yet. Can  you boot into Ubuntu and run the following command line `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`; Did you change the boot mode (in an uefi-bios menu)? Did you install Windows, or upgrade from Windows 7 or was Windows 10 factory installed?

Comment: The output of that command was 'bios'  so it is in legacy

Comment: Did you change the boot mode (in an uefi-bios menu)? Did you install Windows, or upgrade from Windows 7 or was Windows 10 factory installed? (Factory installed Windows 10 boos in uefi mode, upgraded Windows from 7 boots in legacy mode, I'm not sure about upgrades from 8 or 8.1 (maybe uefi, maybe legacy mode). -- Can you check in the uefi/bios menu system, it should tell which boot mode is set, and you should be able to switch between the boot modes. -- It should be possible to add uefi boot to grub by installing the package `grub-efi` and use it to create a boot system for uefi mode.

Comment: @Kingrain, See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) and detailed instructions at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213631&page=4&p=13468260#post13468260).